# BootstrapMethodError caused by LambdaConversionException caused by using MethodHandle::invokeExact as a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, invokedynamic, methodhandle

I was trying to check if it is possible to use MethodHandle::invoke or MethodHandle::invokeExact as method references for a functional interface that accepts a MethodHandle and returns a generified output.

*(I know that invoke and invokeExact are signature polymorphic, hence the metafactory call in InvokeExact. However, I wanted to know if the compiler is able to elide the things that I had to do to derive a suitable version of invoke/invokeExact.)*

**invoke.InvokeExact0**

```
package invoke;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.lookup;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface InvokeExact0<OUTPUT> {
  public OUTPUT invokeExact(MethodHandle methodHandle) throws Throwable;

  public static <OUTPUT> InvokeExact0<OUTPUT> new_(InvokeExact0<OUTPUT> invokeExact) {
    return invokeExact;
  }

  public static void main(String... arguments) throws Throwable {
    out.println(
      (InvokeExact0<String>) metafactory(
        lookup(),
        "invokeExact",
        methodType(InvokeExact0.class),
        methodType(
          Object.class,
          MethodHandle.class
        ),
        lookup().findVirtual(
          MethodHandle.class,
          "invokeExact",
          methodType(String.class)
        ),
        methodType(
          String.class,
          MethodHandle.class
        )
      )
        .getTarget()
        .invokeExact()
    );
    out.println(InvokeExact0.new_(MethodHandle::invokeExact));
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
invoke.InvokeExact0$$Lambda$1/1878246837@5ca881b5                                                                                                                         
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception                                                                             
        at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:328)                                                                                                          
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:296)                                                                                
        at invoke.InvokeExact0.main(InvokeExact0.java:41)                                                                                                                 
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Incorrect number of parameters for instance method invokeVirtual java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeExact:(MethodH
andle)Object; 0 captured parameters, 1 functional interface method parameters, 1 implementation parameters                                                                
        at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:193)                                     
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)                                                                                     
        at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:289)                                                                                                          
        ... 2 more
```

The good news is that the metafactory approach was able to synthesize a working functional interface instance (as printed: *invoke.InvokeExact0$$Lambda$1/1878246837@1be6f5c3*).
The bad news is that the method reference approach resulted in a LambdaConversionException, which in turn resulted in a BootstrapMethodError.

**I would then like to ask how I am supposed to interpret the error details in LambdaConversionException, since the metafactory workaround exists anyway.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code calling `metafactory` manually indeed shows that the meta factory will do its job if the method handle to `MethodHandle.invokeExact` has the right signature. Debugging revealed that in the second case the method handle has a `(MethodHandle,MethodHandle)Object` signature where it should be `(MethodHandle)Object`.

While both can be created without a problem as `MethodHandle.invokeExact` allows arbitrary signatures (well, its first argument has to be `MethodHandle`, of course), the metafactory rejects the handle because it doesn't match the functional signature as there is no second method handle in scope.

This indicates a bug in the compiler which generated the method handle constant. Generally, if you have non-reflective code, and `InvokeExact0.new_(MethodHandle::invokeExact)` *refers* to a reflective operation but doesn't *perform* the reflective operation, but get a runtime error, it indicates a compiler bug.

There is a simple work-around. While

```java
InvokeExact0<Object> ie = MethodHandle::invokeExact;
```

fails with said error,

```java
InvokeExact0<Object> ie = mh -> mh.invokeExact();
```

works as expected. You will need a lambda expression in place of the method reference anyway, as soon as you want different return types as in

```java
InvokeExact0<String> ie = mh -> (String) mh.invokeExact();
```