# generic types paired with method references

Tags: generics, lambda, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have stumbled into this by accident. Here is the short story. In some code-base there are a bunch of enums that follow the same pattern, here is one that is greatly simplified:

```
enum Letters {
    A("a"),
    Z("z");

    private String value;

    Letters(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Letters> MAP;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    static {
        MAP = Arrays.stream(values())
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                            Letters::getValue,
                            Function.identity()
                        ),
                        ImmutableMap::copyOf
                    ));
    }

    public static Optional<Letters> fromValue(String value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(MAP.get(value));
    }
}
```

This is a pattern across tens of Enums, literally, and no this can't be changed. I thought about changing this code duplication, since it's *a lot* of it.

My idea was to start with an enum interface, that all will implement:

```
interface GetValueInterface {
    String getValue();
}
```

And some common code that will handle this MAP creation (`fromValue` would be handled there too, but let's put that aside). So, something like this:

```
 static class EnumsCommon {

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & GetValueInterface> Map<String, T> getAsMap(Class<T> clazz) {
        T[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();

        return Arrays.stream(values)
                     .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                         Collectors.toMap(
                             T::getValue,
                             Function.identity()
                         ),
                         ImmutableMap::copyOf
                     ));
    }
}
```

So the code looks like this now:

```
enum Letters implements GetValueInterface {

    // everything else stays the same
    static {
        MAP = EnumsCommon.getAsMap(Letters.class);
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I run it under `java-8`, there is an exception thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type class java.lang.Enum; not a subtype of implementation type interface GetValueInterface

Running the same code under `java-11` works just fine...

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [LambdaConversionException with generics: JVM bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031244/lambdaconversionexception-with-generics-jvm-bug) or [BootstrapMethodError caused by LambdaConversionException caused by using MethodHandle::invokeExact as a method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394032/bootstrapmethoderror-caused-by-lambdaconversionexception-caused-by-using-methodh)? Well explained by Holger in both the references.

Comment: Why `T::getValue` instead of just `GetValueInterface::getValue`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I initially tried that also, with the same result though

Comment: OK, seems it was a type inference bug that has been fixed. The solution (as you've shown in your self answer) is to not use a method reference and provide an argument with an explicit type to the lambda expression.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I don't think it was a type inference bug btw, but more of what gets erased and how, it should have been erased to `GetValueInterface`, instead it is to an enum, if there would be two interfaces, simply swapping them would resolve it too, it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After preparing this question for 20 minutes, I did a google search and found the issue immediately :|  [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141508)

The fix is easy, just use a lambda expression:

```
(T t) -> t.getValue() // instead of T::getValue
```

Comment: If you still want to use a method reference, you have to use `(Function<GetValueInterface,String>)GetValueInterface::getValue`. It will be accepted by the `toMap` collector, due to the PECS rule, but has no relationship to `T` nor `Enum` anymore. That’s a bit like in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33929304/2711488). By the way, you may consider using a [`ClassValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ClassValue.html) instance in the interface for caching, instead of having a field in every implementation class.

Comment: @Holger unfortunately I did not understand the `ClassValue` proposal, it's actually first time I heard about it