# What does “MethodHandle::invoke” mean in Java?

Tags: java, methodhandle

Look the follow code:

```java
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

public class Demo {
    interface TFunction<T, R> {
        R apply(T t) throws Throwable;
    }

    public class MyMethodHandle {
        public final native Object invoke(Object... args) throws Throwable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TFunction<MyMethodHandle, Object> f1 = m -> m.invoke();
        TFunction<MyMethodHandle, Object> f2 = MyMethodHandle::invoke;

        TFunction<MethodHandle, Object> f3 = m -> m.invoke();
        TFunction<MethodHandle, Object> f4 = MethodHandle::invoke; // here is line 19
    }
}
```

run it(java 8), and I get a exception at f4:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at x.xxx.Demo.main(Demo.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Incorrect number of parameters for instance method invokeVirtual java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invoke:(Object)Object; 0 captured parameters, 1 functional interface method parameters, 1 implementation parameters
    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:193)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
    ... 3 more
```

my question is what is the difference between f3 and f4? and why f2 can work but f4 not?

I have no idea, I searched for this but got no answer.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) (and others) (at least, addresses the question in the title).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BootstrapMethodError caused by LambdaConversionException caused by using MethodHandle::invokeExact as a method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394032/bootstrapmethoderror-caused-by-lambdaconversionexception-caused-by-using-methodh)

Comment: As an aside, the code as given will not compile with Java, so I don't see how it can give that exception at runtime. The compilation error is _"Demo.java:17: error: method invoke in class MethodHandle cannot be applied to given types;"_.

Comment: Never mind, it doesn't compile with Java 11, 17 and 21, but it does seem to compile with Java 8, and then produce the error at runtime.

Comment: Are you also running it with Java 8?

Comment: Seems my title is not good enough, but I don't know how to express it correctly, sorry for my poor english. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: yes @dan1stiscrying

Comment: I think the `::` operator expects the `Object[]` to be a parameter.

Comment: Works when compiling with Eclipse. It’s important to understand that the methods `invoke` and `invokeExact` *from `MethodHandle`* are [signature polymorphic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#sigpoly) but arbitrary `final native` methods are not.